# Incorrect output in an array inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a struct with an int array inside that I'm passing to a function for the array to be initialized

array struct like so..

```
typedef struct Container{
    struct intArray *P;
    int length;
} Container;

typedef struct intArray{
    int *array;
    int length;
} intArray;
```

function to initialize the array
like so...

```
int Initializer(intArray *myStruct, int n)
{
    myStruct->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (lengthOfint);
                                              ^
                                        If n=55 then length would be 2
    //let's just say n=5
    myStruct->array[0] = n;

    //return 1 if successful
    return 1;
}
```

In another function I am calling the initializer function like so...

```
Container *myContainer = malloc(sizeof(Container));

myContainer->P = malloc(sizeof(intArray *) * Some_Defined_Value);

Initializer(&myContainer, 5);

printf("the data that should be at index 0 -> %d\n", myContainer->P.array[0];
```

I would think that the printf statement would print out 5 but it prints out garbage of varying numbers every time I compile it. I don't think I have a grasp of the array within a struct within a struct idea.

Comment: Please post code that could compile...`myStruct->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (lengthOfint);` is missing a close parenthesis.  Also, I'm puzzled how `n=55` leads to `lengthOfint == 2`; are you measuring in bits and assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` and `CHAR_BIT == 8`?  Not unreasonable assumptions, but the use of a bit count is not so obvious.

Comment: I think, op means something to the likes of `lengthOfint == ceil(log10(abs(n)))`.

Comment: The idea behind that is that I need to store a number into a int array so 12345 would be in an intArray[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}...So 55 would yield an array of size 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Container` holds a pointer to `struct intArray`, which in this case is the start of an array of `struct intArray`. But then you initialize this pointer with

```
malloc(sizeof(intArray *) * Some_Defined_Value);
```

So malloc returns a pointer to a memory space which holds **pointers** to `struct intArray` because you used `sizeof(intArray *)` and not `sizeof(intArray)` (you allocated space for `Some_Defined_Value` number of **pointers**).

You need `sizeof(intArray) * Some_Defined_Value` here to allocate space for `Some_Defined_Value` number of `struct intArray`'s.

Then you use

```
Initializer(&myContainer, 5);
```

which should at least give a warning because you pass a **pointer** to a **pointer** to a `struct Container`, but `Initializer` expects a **pointer** to a `struct intArray`, so this is not what you want. To initialize the first element of your array of `struct intArray`'s use:

```
Initializer(&(myContainter->P[0]), 5);
```

Then:

```
printf("the data that should be at index 0 -> %d\n", myContainer->P.array[0]));
```

This code does not compile because it should be:

```
printf("the data that should be at index 0 -> %d\n", myContainer->P[0].array[0]);
```

`myContainer->P` accesses a **pointer** to a `struct intArray`. The code right above means you access the first element (element number 0) of the array of `struct intArray`'s .

To initialize/access the second element of the array of `struct intArray`'s use:

```
Initializer(&(myContainter->P[1]), 5);
printf("the data that should be at index 0 -> %d\n", myContainer->P[1].array[0]);
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve A single container which holds an array of structs. Inside of each of these structs are an int array which holds an integer represented in array form -> 12345 is an array[5]={1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: Then you should be fine with the end of what I wrote. If you want to initialize the 2nd `intArray` inside your Container, you need `Initializer(&(myContainer->P[1]));` and to access it (after initialization), `myContainter->P[1].array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the container to the initializer function, but if you look closely you'll see that the you are passing a pointer to a pointer to the "outer" container instead of a pointer to the desired `struct intArray`. You'd want something like `Initializer(myContainer->P, 5);`

Comment: the compiler tells me that's an incompatible type argument for Initializer when I do that, that's the only reason I changed it to &myContainer. of course the code I have sampled here is not the complete thing but it's pretty accurate.

Comment: It's an incompatible pointer type because the types `Container` and `intArray` are indeed incompatible. Trying to cast `Container**` to `intarray*` instead doesn't make it better. These warnings exist for a reason!

Comment: So what's the work around, no matter what this is the infrastructure I'm trying to implement -> A container which holds multiple intArray structs and each intArray struct holds an int array with different amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware that `malloc` returns a `void *` so most of the time you'll need a cast like so:

```
myStruct->array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (length);
//                ^^^^^^
```

Assuming `length` is the number of int you want to store in your array.